# Price Annualizing in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Hi I am using the following calculation to annualize a price field.

```
(price  *  365 / close _date - begin_date ) *  9.35/100
```

This calculation is working when  leap year is involved

for example  when price = 6000

begin date = 1-jan- 2016

close date  = 31-dec-2017

so the annualized value is 280.50

But when I change  begin dates & end date to  1-jan-2017 and 31-dec-2018, the value changes to 280.88

How do I get  the values to 280.50  in both the cases?can any  averaging be done so that the value comes perfectly when any date is involved ?

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result. Show us the whole query (perhaps simplified.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `months_between()`:

```
select price  *  12 / months_between(close _date, begin_date ) *  9.35/100
```

You may have to adjust the boundaries by one day for it to work for your dates:

```
select price  *  12 / months_between(close _date + 1, begin_date) *  9.35/100
```

Note:  `months_between()` is a little tricky because it returns fractional months.  However, if the difference is always to the first of the month, then you are safe.

Comment: The OP seems to want an amount per day, so this is not likely to help - he will want a different amount from Jan 1 to Jan 31 than from April 1 to April 30. (Actually I happen to know that's what he is looking for, he posted the same on OTN.)

Answer (score 1):

2016 is a Leap Year.. 366 days. While 2017 has 365 days

Your Denom slips from 730 days to 729 days